# Check allow multiuser property of people field using CSOM C#

Tags: development, csom, user

I want to implement code based upon whether people field is multi user or single user. I am using below code but **user field is coming null.**

```
FieldUser user = RequestsList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Approver") as FieldUser;
ctx.Load(user);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
if (user.AllowMultipleValues == true)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Whats wrong in the code? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because CSOM field object can't be converted to FieldUser object like this, "user" object will return null after converting.
The valid way to check if a user field is multiple user or single user value, check the TypeString like below:

```
                var client = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("http://sp/");
                List list = client.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CSOMUser");
                client.Load(list.Fields);
                client.ExecuteQuery();
                Field user = list. Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("testuser") ;
                client.Load(user);
                client.ExecuteQuery();

                if (user.TypeAsString == "UserMulti")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is a multiple user field");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is a single user field");
                }
```

For multiple user field, Type String is UserMulti.
For single user fieled, Type String is just User.

[image]